# Real Time Multiplayer Game

Tags: google-play-games

How to get current participant id in `onRoomConnceted` method? Previously I used 
`myId = room.getParticipantId(getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayerId());` in new update it's not available and how to manage this if not available..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here it is

```
myId = room.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient()));
```